# datalab create hangs on Windows 10

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I get to "Waiting for Datalab to be reachable at http://localhost:8081", PuTTY starts up, I get the "do you want to trust this" dialog, I hit yes.

PuTTY terminal shows:

```
Using username "datalab".
Authenticating with public key "<mymachinename>\<mywindowslogin>@<mymachinename>"
```

And then nothing. It just hangs there.

So then I close the PuTTY window, and it automatically tries to reconnect. At that point, the DOS command window shows:

```
The connection to Datalab is now open and will remain etc.
```

and I can connect. How weird is that? Is there anything I should do to not have to do that?

I really have to get a VM running Ubuntu. Developing on Windows is a pain.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to reproduce the behavior you are seeing. What should be happening (and what I see when I run it) is:

1. A PuTTY window pops up
2. The dialog window asking if I trust the machine gets shown
3. I press "Yes" in that dialog and it goes away.
4. The PuTTY window then prints that message you mentioned about "Using username... Authenticating with public key..."
5. The original command prompt (which may be hidden by the PuTTY window) displays the message about the connection to Datalab being open.
6. A web browser pops open pointing at http://localhost:8081/ and I can see the Datalab UI inside of it.

Can you try opening a browser pointing at http://localhost:8081/ when the PuTTY terminal seems to hang? I wonder if the issue is that the browser isn't opening for some reason, causing it to look like you need to wait even when the connection is set up.